# wifi_set_sta_power results in EPERM Operation isn't permitted

Tags: blackberry-10

I have created this function in my BB10 C application:

```
int setWifiStatus(bool status) {
    int result;
    int errvalue = -10;
    result = wifi_set_sta_power(status);
    if (result != WIFI_SUCCESS) {

        errvalue = errno;
    }

    return errvalue;
}
```

I set the following permission in the bar_descriptor file:

```
<permission>access_wifi_public</permission>
```

The error number 1 (EPERM) Operation Not Permitted is returned in errno when I call the function. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you calling it with `status == false` ? According to the comments on the [API documentation site](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/core/com.qnx.doc.wifi_service.lib_ref/topic/wifi_set_sta_power.html), this call is now only able to turn the WiFi radio on.

Comment: Thanks. I feel kind of silly. It's right there in black and white.